# Elasticsearch. Remove part of my_index/_settings

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have elastic(2.4.6) my_index/_settings:

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "preserve_existing" : "true",
        "max_result_window" : "10000000",
        "{index" : {
          "max_result_window" : ""
        },
        "creation_date" : "66666666",
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "uuid" : "test",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "666"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I remove this part:

```
"{index" : {
              "max_result_window" : ""
            },
```

1. How can I do it?
2. Does this row affect on elastic?

Comment: What's your motivation for removing it? Are you creating a new index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not delete this line. but the empty value is OK and This means that it returns to the default value (10000) . in your case I think it set to 100000.